# 360 degree view in a iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiviewanimation

i want to create 360 degree view of an object in cocoa and ios. what are the possible ways i can do that? what are the inputs i should provide to that. i'm very new to cocoa so please help me with this.

Comment: you want to model 3d objects or what?

Comment: i don't want to model a object. i want something like http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_4-3d-spin-3275.php how can i implement this in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/panoramagl.aspx?fid=1561868&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=1#xx0xx) could help. Frankly speaking, I don't really understand what are you expecting for.

Comment: i wanted something like this in cocoa and ios:-http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_4-3d-spin-3275.php

Comment: I think, you can use the library I've mentioned. The only problem is that you'll have to create proper spherical images, it's a bit tricky for your case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the images, you can shoot 4 - 40 shots around a single rotation to show the product in a "3d" space.